# How to map two values in a dictionary into a single dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

if i have a dictionary

```
Singers = [
 {'Singer_ID': 'S00464040',
  'City': 'BIRMINGHAM',
  'First': ' MARTHA RENEE',
  'Last': 'BOZEMAN',
  'State': 'AL',
  'Zipcode': '35201'},
 {'Singer_ID': 'S00460410',
  'City': 'BIRMINGHAM',
  'First': ' EARL FREDERICK JR',
  'Last': 'HILLIARD',
  'State': 'AL',
  'Zipcode': '35202'},
 {'Singer_ID': 'S00461038',
  'City': 'BIRMINGHAM',
  'First': ' SHEILA',
  'Last': 'SMOOT',
  'State': 'NY',
  'Zipcode': '87201'}]
```

How could I write a function that matches Singer: ID with State?

For example returns:

```
{'S00464040': 'AL',
 'S00460410': 'AL',
 'S00461038': 'NY'}
```

Comment: See [set and dictionary comprehensions](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/#using-set-and-dictionary-comprehensions) for valuable techniques.

Comment: Which part are you struggling with?

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
>>> {i['Singer_ID']: i['State'] for i in Singers}
{'S00464040': 'AL', 'S00460410': 'AL', 'S00461038': 'NY'}
```